# Google Places API reviews confusion

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am aware that the Google Places API returns only 5 reviews. However, I see some software that seems to read all reviews. Take a look at podium.co for example. They seem to be able to read all the reviews, otherwise there is no way for them to pull them in, other than scraping Google, which is of course a crazy thing to do if you are basing your whole business on the reviews.

So, my question is, how do they do it? Does having Premuim (paid) access to the Google Places API give you the option to read all reviews maybe? If not, how does Podium do it then?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 6):

I just spoke to a Google representative, and they told me that if I purchased Premium access to the API, then I can pull all reviews. The Premium access is for multiple APIs, and it gives you quite a lot of stuff to do that you can't do with the free access. There is however a catch though. Premium access costs $10,000 annually, payable upfront for the year. OUCH!!!

Comment: Can you provide more info about what Google told you about Premium access? I just asked the same question to their sales team, and he responded that "There is no way to access any review for a place besides the 5 most recent reviews." I'm hoping that this rep is simply misinformed...

Comment: I have no more info than what  I previously said. You are looking are $10K annually for the Premium account to be able to access all reviews. The Premium account is not only to access the reviews of course, it gives you much, much more than that across all of Google's APIs. It is just sad that you need to pay this in order access only the reviews.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Place API, this is explicit stated in the Official Google Documentation under the review[] field that:

reviews[] a JSON array of up to five reviews.

There is currently no way to retrieve more that 5 reviews.

For Premium Data, based on the Official Google Documentation, you may access to ratings and reviews for locations worldwide. With the Premium Data feature, you can programmatically access enhanced review data as part of the Google Places API Web Service.

Note: Premium data features are considered experimental and subject to change.

For more information, please follow the links below: 
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults.
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/premium-data?hl=vi